# Keyboard shortcut for code refactor (var rename) in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide, refactoring, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

When renaming a variable in Visual Studio (I use 2010), it shows a little mark that when clicked, leads to a drop-down that offers to rename all the dependant references.

[image]

What I want to do, is spare getting the mouse and click it in order to show the drop-down.
I was wondering if there is a way to access it via the keyboard.

Comment: [ALT]+[SHIFT]+[F10], no?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe that shortcut is `Ctrl + .` [dot] :)

Comment: Oh man, that was quick like a chat! "You can accept an answer in 11 minutes" - That's what it says!

Comment: My hero.  I had forgotten that one.

Comment: Ctrl+[dot] does not work for me, but Alt+Shift+F10 does.  Why is this?  Is it because of a configuration tweak? Thanks.

Comment: Sabuncu: Might be because of environment settings (I believe it's being set on first launch or when you reset settings). I am using "general". I know there are some shortcut differences (or at least there were... I haven't used anything but general for some time..)

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to assign your own shortcut, go to Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard, then in the "Show commands containing" field, enter the text View.ShowSmartTag